# Confusion about CUDA installation instructions (What exactly is microsoft visual studio?)

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I have a question regarding the CUDA installation instructions found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html). It says I need a working version of microsoft visual studio. But I am a bit overwhelmed/confused: What exactly *is* MCVS? When I try to download it, it seems to be some kind of IDE. I am fine with my current IDE so I do not wish to change to another IDE. I expected it to be some kind of SDK which you need to install to be able to use CUDA.

Comment: Yes it is IDE, and CUDA adds a project template to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio is an IDE, but it also packages Microsoft's C++ compiler (unaptly named Microsoft Visual C++) and other pieces of software.

You will not have to use MS Visual Studio as your IDE when you work with CUDA - but it's still a requirement, because CUDA compilation will involve the MSVC compiler. Also, CUDA integrates into MS Visual Studio in various ways, facilitating development, debugging and profiling; and that will not be available to you with other IDEs.

---

<sub>You may also wish to consider doing CUDA development on Linux instead of Windows, where CUDA is not tied to any IDE, nor to a single compiler (although it has its preferences).</sub>

Comment: Thanks. When launching the installer, I can choose from a wide variety of individual components. Is there no way to simply pick the MSVC compiler I need, and nothing else?

Comment: There are so many components that I can instal; I don't know which ones I need and which ones i don't (To use CUDA)

Comment: You need to install the C++ toolchain. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Psychotechnopath: What Robert says. Although you probably don't even need all of the C++-related components.

Comment: That clarifies a lot - Thanks